Usb Error message while using Selenium with Python for webscraping
I'm new to web scraping.
As a practice, I wanted to scrape some data from this site "https://www.egx.com.eg/ar/homepage.aspx", It's the Official website for Egyptian Market Exchange and it doesn't need any credentials to preview the content.
While using this code :
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.egx.com.eg")

I get this error message in my vscode terminal:

[13004:17320:0504/180535.614:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(195)] [18:05:35.614] USB: usb_service_win.cc:105 SetupDiGetDeviceProperty({{A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0}, 6}) failed: Element not found. (0x490)

Any Idea what could cause this Error message?
Hint
The website loads normally when I open it manually but when I'm using Selenium or Soup it gives no access

That message can be ignored. It's just for info and doesn't affect the script function.
